# How to use multiple CSV files for machine learning anomaly detection

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, classification, anomaly-detection

I have a question about how to get my data in a shape that I can use for my ML model. I have multiple CSV files that I want to fit in an algorithm for anomaly detection. My data consists of many files with each being the recorded data from a sensor with two features (intensity and depth) and one timestamp per data point. Each file is labeled with 0 = faulty data and 1 = good data.

Let's say I have 20 files: `y` should be the label per file `y = [[1], [0], ...]` and `X` should be all the data from the sensor `X = [[data_file0], [data_file1], ..., [data_file19]]` that I can use to train my models. What can I do to get my data in the right format? I tried appending the data frame of every file to a list and transformed it to a dataset and a `np.array` and so on. I tried different shapes too.

```
    all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
    
    df_list = []  
    snr_list = []
    for filename in all_files:
        #Für jede Datei wird ein df angelegt und unwichtige features entfernt
        #try with dataset with filename and all_files
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(all_files)
        
        def parse_fn(filename):
            return tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
        
        dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda x:
             tf.data.TextLineDataset(x).map(parse_fn, num_parallel_calls=1),
             cycle_length=4, block_length=16)

        #try df_list    
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0, header=0, decimal = '.', delimiter = ';')
        df.drop(columns=['ET_original', 'Auslenkung_ET', 'ET_unkorrigiert'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
        
        #Zu jedem Zeitpunkt wird der Startzeitpunkt abgezogen: t0 = 1 ... tn = t_n - t0

        starttime = df.Zeit_ET[0]
        for row in df.itertuples():
            df.at[row.Index, 'Zeit_ET'] = df.Zeit_ET[row.Index] - starttime
        df.Zeit_ET[0] = 1
        
    
        #alle arrays einer List hinzufügen
        df_list.append(df.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1700, 3))
        

        #other testings
        #test = tf.constant(pd.DataFrame(dic, columns=['1', '1', ' 1']))
        #ps=pd.DataFrame(dic, index=['dsf'])
           
    #df_list, test_df (1 df), und tf_const (1 df) zurückgeben         
    return df_list, df.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1700, 3), tf.constant(df.to_numpy().reshape(1, 1700, 3), dtype = tf.float32)

#nur für Testzwecke
df_list, test_df, tf_const = Alle_OCT_txt_Daten()
```

Comment: Before I can help you with the answer, I need to clarify a few things. Do each of the sensors take readings at the same exact times in a way that we can line them all up with a single time column?

Comment: No, each pair (each row) of  data point has its own timestemp.

Comment: And each file has multiple timestamped datapoints?

Comment: As I wrote above, i have multiple data, here are the first 6 data points of one of my file
note: Zeit_ET = a timestamp preprocessed to ns with t0 = 1 (see Code)
`columns = ['timestamp', 'Intensity', 'depth'],  array([[  1.        ,  79.        ,  -0.5273184 ],
       [ 14.        ,  94.        ,  -0.56211778],
       [ 29.        , 102.        ,  -0.59692583],
       [ 43.        , 109.        ,  -0.57392274],
       [ 57.        , 111.        ,  -0.55091889]])` 

there are 6 rows from 1700

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the files are the same, but each has a distinct time stamp, right. Juts load everything into a dataframe and run your AI or ML algo on the dataframe.

```
# import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
  
  
# use glob to get all the csv files 
# in the folder
path = 'C:\\your_path_here\\'
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
  
  
li = []

for filename in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
print(frame)
```

Comment: hey, sry for the late reply. And nope, that did not worked

Comment: It worked fine for me. What's the exact issue?